# DataMapper model in a rails mountable engine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, datamapper, ruby-on-rails-plugins, rails-engines

I'm building a mountable engine.

From a basic install, I've moved my existing application into the engine namespace.

The engine starts, but I've getting error messages because there are no tables in a db for the controller to reference.

- How do I get my models in a database from the engine?
- How can I test this with the provided dummy app?

I looked into dm-migrations, but I've yet to use that with DataMapper, so I'm sort of in clueless, uncharted waters. Giant question marks and all that. I'll poke around, but there is nothing through a search that is useful, right now.

Here is the application I'm playing with:
http://github.com/blueblank/Ticket-Engine

Comment: There doesn't seem to be quick answer to this right now, a migration works somewhat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple and straight forward answer is to create a generator that copies the models to the main app. That is it and simple, though looking at it in the long run, having the dm models in the engines app/models folder as the only prerequisite for installing models to an application from an engine (or mountable engine) would be fantastic.